# Find user by sAMAccountName VBA

Tags: vba, excel, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to find a user in AD by their sAMAccountName. Here's my code:

```
sQuery = "<LDAP://OU=theOU,DC=mainDC,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=sAMA));distinguishedName,sAMAccountName;subtree"
```

I execute this query by

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open _
"Data Source=Active Directory Provider;Provider=ADsDSOObject"
Set rs = conn.Execute(sQuery)
```

The query doesn't fails. I've also tried changing the query to this:

```
<LDAP://OU=theOU,DC=mainDC,DC=com>;(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=sAMA));subtree
```

but that fails as well.

I'm doing this in VBA, any help is much appreciated!

The error I get is:

```
A referral was returned from the server.
```

Also, is there an easier way to search multiple domains other than just query twice?

Thanks!

Comment: Which is it - doesn't return anything? or does it fail? For starters, I would say that `objectclass=user` and `objectcategory=Person` are redundant. Is your user's samaccountname `sAMA`?

Comment: It fails. and yes the user's samaaccountname is sAMA

Comment: I believe the error it throws it about a reference returned?

Comment: I updated the main post with the error.

Comment: a referral is not an error, it is the server responding saying that it cannot find what you are asking for locally but it offers another server.  What other information was returned with the referral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was add this:

```
objCommand.Properties("Chase referrals") = ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_ALWAYS
```

The connection code is:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Chase referrals") = ADS_CHASE_REFERRALS_ALWAYS

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set dom = GetObject("LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
objCommand.CommandText = "<" & dom.ADsPath & ">;" & _
    "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=" & LoginName & "));" & _
    "distinguishedName,sAMAccountName;subtree"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

This works fine now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found this snippet, give it a try. Change line 1 with your AD and line 2 for sAMA:

```
StartNode = "cn=Users,dc=fabrikam,dc=com" 'edit with your values
strAccount = "HMustermann" 'edit with your searchvalue

Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
SearchScope = "subtree"

FilterString = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & strAccount & "))"
Attributes = "adspath"

LDAPQuery = "<LDAP://" & StartNode & ">;" & FilterString & ";" _
        & Attributes & ";" & SearchScope

objCommand.CommandText = LDAPQuery
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1500
objCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
objCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set objRecordset = objCommand.Execute

If Not objRecordset.EOF Then
   objRecordset.MoveFirst

   Do Until objRecordset.EOF
      strUserPath = objRecordset.Fields("ADsPath").Value
      Set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)
      '-------get attributes -----------
      MsgBox objUser.DisplayName
      '--------------------------------------
      objRecordset.MoveNext
   Loop
End If

objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close
MsgBox "Finish"
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but it still didn't fix my issue. I did manage to figure it out though, so I'll add that as an answer. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `A referral was returned from the server.` usually means you are trying to get an object in domainA when connected to domainB.

Please try to use:

```
<LDAP://mainDC.com/OU=theOU,DC=mainDC,DC=com>
```

instead of:

```
<LDAP://OU=theOU,DC=mainDC,DC=com>
```

Without a server it will connect to the domain of current computer (or user?), which may not be mainDC.com.

To search from all domains in forest, you may use the GC:

```
<GC://[GC server]>
```

But please note that only a subset of attributes exists on GC.